# Creating a SQL lookup

Tags: sql, sql-server

I’m in the process of cleaning up a database table. Due to the way some of the data needed to be processed, now I need to go back and perform a “reverse lookup” on the data. For example, a field for one of the records is set to “car” and I need to set that record’s tranportmode field to “1” (for “car”). The lookup tables are already created. I just need to do the reverse lookup part. The cleansed tables will only have the numeric lookup value.

Comment: Can you post your table definitions?

Comment: Are you asking about the one time operation (the update of facts table with dimension ID), or are you asking about the contiguous maintenance of this relation (ie. add new values a they show up)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyTable.TransportMode = mlt.TransportMode 
FROM MyTable mt 
INNER JOIN MyLookupTable mlt ON mt.Name = mlt.Name
```

Comment: Upvote : assumes you split the table into two.  One of those would be a "transportation type table" having values (Car,1), (Bus,2) or something similar.

Also I would assume you would create a foreign key relationship once the data is all in order.

Comment: @John: yes, OP says they have created lookup tables

Comment: I think the join should be "on mt.Name = mlt.Name"

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to be concerned about the integrity of the original data at all? Would it be more appropriate to utilize a view and a case statement to generate your numeric fields? Or perhaps more straight forward would be to add a column to your lookup table that contains the numeric fields and then construct a view that only contains that information? There's just something about updating a raw data field that doesn't seem like the optimal solution to me.

Comment: This is actually columns for both the numeric key value and the textual value in the table. No an optimal design but sometimes you inherit those projects...